# how can i change the width and height from fetching post images in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm fetching the post images in a loop and each of which would display with new width and height. I'm having problem in how should i define width and height in img tag.

```
<?php
 $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID() ),
         'single-post-thumbnail'); 
?>
<img src="<?= $image[0]; ?>" alt="" width="" height="" />
```

Comment: Unless you can set it as a variable then I'd suggest just not bothering to set it.

Comment: Take a look at : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 0):

array getimagesize ( string $filename [, array &$imageinfo ] )

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Also, from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

```
<?php 
    $attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); // returns an array
?> 

<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
```